# php parse date from a string such as Sun 5th Jan

Tags: php, parsing, datetime

im trying to parse a date from a string using date_create_from_format(). the date string looks like this: Sun 5th Jan
i was expecting this to work

```
$dateFromString = date_create_from_format("D jS M", "Sun 5th Jan");
```

Doesnt work though, anyone know why?

Comment: PHP Version 5.4.9-4ubuntu2.4

Comment: "Does not work" means what exactly, what kind of date are you getting?

Comment: The format string looks ok, but you're not specifying a year, maybe it's that

Answer (score 0):

That is just the format.. You need to use it !

```
<?php
$dateFromString = date_create_from_format("D jS M", "Sun 5th Jan");
echo $dateFromString->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```